# I want to integrate my Careers profile to MVA (Microsoft Virtual Academy) site

Tags: feature-request, support, status-declined, jobs

The Stack Overflow Careers site/profile page supports a lot of integration to other accounts like [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub), [CodePlex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePlex), etc. I want my MVA (Microsoft Virtual Academy) profile to link with the Stack Overflow Careers profile. Do you guys plan to link it as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I can tell MVA [doesn't have an API](http://trainingsupport.microsoft.com/en-us/tcmva/forum/tcmvaother-tcmvaprodother/is-there-an-api-for-the-microsoft-virtual-academy/ad860fd4-1912-4795-86ca-51e7ab29eab9) we can use to link to it.

You can certainly make your Careers profile public and use the URL in your MVA profile, and presumably vice versa if MVA has the notion of public profiles.

But other than that I can't see anything happening in the short to medium term unless an API becomes available!